# get list of keys in xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm adding variables to an xarray Dataset, and when I'm done, I want to extract a list of the keys, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

```
d = xr.Dataset()
d['key1'] = [1, 2]
d['key2'] = [3, 4]
```

My desired result is

```
keylist = ['key1', 'key2']
```

Comment: You have tried `list(d.keys())`, have you?

Answer (score 6):

At least from version 0.16.1 you have to type in:

```
list(d.keys())
['key1', 'key2']
```

to get the variable keys as a list.

Answer (score 2):

Just type:

```
d.keys()
```

It yields:

```
In [53]: d.keys()
Out[53]: ['key1', 'key2']
```

Or if you really want them to be called keylist:

```
In [54]: keylist = d.keys()

In [55]: keylist
Out[55]: ['key1', 'key2']
```

The python dictionary structure implemented in xarray is demonstrated in detail in the documentation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html#dataset-contents).